# Google Sheets Function trying to rename a sheet

Tags: google-sheets

The following function is designed to get my spreadsheet, add a new tab, insert a new tab with a query that runs, and then save the new tab under a new name. 
Everything works except the new tab always is inserted as then next unused tab number and not renamed. Tried a number of variations (setName, etc.) and nothing seems to work. 
Help!

```
function costIncome() {
var spreadsheetId =https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/thisIsTheSheetID/edit';  
var targetRange = 'PlaySheet!B:F';
var SELECT = 'select B,E,F,sum(C) ';
var WHERE = ' ';
var GROUPBY = ' group by B,F,E order by D,B';
var HAVING = ' ';
var SQL = SELECT + WHERE + GROUPBY + HAVING;

//var SQL = 'select B,E,F,sum(C) group by B,F,E';
var Query = '=QUERY('+targetRange+',\"'+SQL+'\")';

var currentDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetId);
currentDoc.insertSheet('costfunds');  

var pushQuery = currentDoc.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(Query);
var pullResult = currentDoc.getDataRange().getValues();

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get Active spreadsheet object
var sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(); // Get Active sheet's object
sh.setName("Name changed!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer elsewhere
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
tempSheet.setName("MYCHANGEDSHEET");

I lost the link for the original post, but thanks to him/her/them.
So many things are poorly functioning/documented in G-Sheets. SMH.